# Map route view does not show correctly in Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, apple-maps

[image]

I implement a map and it works well. But when I try to zoom in the map, I see this problem facing:

Here is my code:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:(id)overlay];
        renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor]; // pathColor;
        renderer.lineWidth = 7.0;
        return  renderer;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the code which you have added

Comment: What do you want to do Sir? You want to zoom or you want to show route?

Comment: Route Display properly but when i Zoom In/Out Fastly this kind of issue occur